# Unfortunately (App Name) has stopped. (I get no errors in eclipse.)

Tags: android

I was developing my first app and I keep getting this error when i run it on my phone.
I am trying to make an app for tic tac toe.
I am a complete beginner to programming, please help me out.

**Main_activity.java** :

```
    package com.example.test3;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    char[][] a;
        char b;
        int j,k,o=0;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        for(j=0;j<3;j++)
        {for(k=0;k<3;k++)
        {
            a[j][k]=' ';
        }
        }
        Button btn1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Btn1);
        Button btn2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Btn2);
        Button btn3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Btn3);
        Button btn4 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Btn4);
        Button btn5 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Btn5);
        Button btn6 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Btn6);
        Button btn7 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Btn7);
        Button btn8 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Btn8);
        Button btn9 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Btn9);

        for(int i=0;i<9;i++)
        {
            if(i%2==0)  {b='X';}
            else        {b='O';}

        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {TextView op1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Btn1);
             op1.setText(b);a[0][0]=b;j=0;k=0;
             check(a,j,k,o);
        }});
        btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {TextView op2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Btn2);
             op2.setText(b);a[0][1]=b;j=0;k=1;
             check(a,j,k,o);
        }});
        btn3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {TextView op3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Btn3);
             op3.setText(b);a[0][2]=b;j=0;k=2;
             check(a,j,k,o);
        }});
        btn4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {TextView op4 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Btn4);
             op4.setText(b);a[1][0]=b;j=1;k=0;
             check(a,j,k,o);
        }});
        btn5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {TextView op5 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Btn5);
             op5.setText(b);a[1][1]=b;j=1;k=1;
             check(a,j,k,o);
        }});
        btn6.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {TextView op6 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Btn6);
             op6.setText(b);a[1][2]=b;j=1;k=2;
             check(a,j,k,o);
        }});
        btn7.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {TextView op7 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Btn7);
             op7.setText(b);a[2][0]=b;j=2;k=0;
             check(a,j,k,o);
        }});
        btn8.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {TextView op8 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Btn8);
             op8.setText(b);a[2][1]=b;j=2;k=1;
             check(a,j,k,o);
        }});
        btn9.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {TextView op9 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Btn9);
             op9.setText(b);a[2][2]=b;j=2;k=2;
             check(a,j,k,o);
        }});

        if(o!=0) {i=9;}
        }

    }


    public void check(char[][] a,int j,int k,int o)
    {
        if(a[j][0]==a[j][1]&&a[j][1]==a[j][2]&&a[j][0]!=' ') o+=1;
        if(a[0][k]==a[1][k]&&a[1][k]==a[2][k]&&a[0][k]!=' ') o+=1;
        if(((a[0][0]==a[1][1]&&a[1][1]==a[2][2])||(a[0][2]==a[1][1]&&a[1][1]==a[2][0]))&&a[1][1]!=' ') o+=1;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

**activity_main.xml**:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/TableLayout01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center">

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/TableRow1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1">
            <Button

                android:text="@string/Btn1"
                android:id="@+id/Btn1"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            </Button>
            <Button

                android:text="@string/Btn2"
                android:id="@+id/Btn2"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            </Button>
            <Button

                android:text="@string/Btn3"
                android:id="@+id/Btn3"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            </Button>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/TableRow2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1">
            <Button

                android:text="@string/Btn4"
                android:id="@+id/Btn4"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            </Button>
            <Button

                android:text="@string/Btn5"
                android:id="@+id/Btn5"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            </Button>
            <Button

                android:text="@string/Btn6"
                android:id="@+id/Btn6"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                </Button>
                </TableRow>
    <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/TableRow3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1">
            <Button

                android:text="@string/Btn7"
                android:id="@+id/Btn7"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            </Button>
            <Button

                android:text="@string/Btn8"
                android:id="@+id/Btn8"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            </Button>
            <Button

                android:text="@string/Btn9"
                android:id="@+id/Btn9"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                </Button>
                </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

**LOGCAT**:

```
03-18 00:25:39.138: I/Process(17623): Sending signal. PID: 17623 SIG: 9
03-18 00:25:51.378: D/AndroidRuntime(17794): Shutting down VM
03-18 00:25:51.378: W/dalvikvm(17794): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41db9ba8)
03-18 00:25:51.378: E/AndroidRuntime(17794): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-18 00:25:51.378: E/AndroidRuntime(17794): Process: com.example.test3, PID: 17794
03-18 00:25:51.378: E/AndroidRuntime(17794): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.test3/com.example.test3.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-18 00:25:51.378: E/AndroidRuntime(17794):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
03-18 00:25:51.378: E/AndroidRuntime(17794):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
03-18 00:25:51.378: E/AndroidRuntime(17794):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
03-18 00:25:51.378: E/AndroidRuntime(17794):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
03-18 00:25:51.378: E/AndroidRuntime(17794):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-18 00:25:51.378: E/AndroidRuntime(17794):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
03-18 00:25:51.378: E/AndroidRuntime(17794):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
03-18 00:25:51.378: E/AndroidRuntime(17794):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-18 00:25:51.378: E/AndroidRuntime(17794):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-18 00:25:51.378: E/AndroidRuntime(17794):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
03-18 00:25:51.378: E/AndroidRuntime(17794):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
03-18 00:25:51.378: E/AndroidRuntime(17794):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-18 00:25:51.378: E/AndroidRuntime(17794): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-18 00:25:51.378: E/AndroidRuntime(17794):    at com.example.test3.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:22)
03-18 00:25:51.378: E/AndroidRuntime(17794):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
03-18 00:25:51.378: E/AndroidRuntime(17794):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
03-18 00:25:51.378: E/AndroidRuntime(17794):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
03-18 00:25:51.378: E/AndroidRuntime(17794):    ... 11 more
03-18 00:25:56.948: I/Process(17794): Sending signal. PID: 17794 SIG: 9
```

Comment: `char[][] a` is null. It has been declared but not initialised.

Comment: `(I get no errors in eclipse.)`.  Think about this.  It means nothing.  You cannot get runtime errors until you fix the compiler errors (which are the only errors Eclipse will tell you about).  If it was true that if Eclipse showed no errors, then the app will run OK, then there would be no crashing apps!

Comment: did these given answers help you?

Comment: Yes, they did. Thank you very much Ken, Simon and Hamid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare your `a[][]` with size before inserting any value to the array as below...

```
char[][] a = new char[3][3];
```

Since, you are not defining any size to `a[][]` array then when you are trying put any value to that array, it can't find the position in that array to insert the value. That's why, its throwing this `Exception`...

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that you're using your array like:

```
a[j][k]=' ';
```

before allocating memory for it.  You'll want to allocate memory for your array before trying to access the elements.

you need to do something like:

```
a = new char[3][3];
```